# .NET library to run performance test for web

Tags: c#, .net, fiddler, load-testing, performance-testing

I have test written on C# with Selenium Webdriver.
now i need testing performance of application.
i used FiddlerCore but it doesn't have page rendering time or time of dynamiс content(ajax,js and etc.).

Anybody know library like FiddlerCore but with more features like dynatrace Ajax edition or browsermob-proxy for C#?

**EDIT 1:** I don't need any solutions. I want to test with WebDriver only.

Answer (score 4):

I've created performace test use BrowserMob as following
- Download lastest BrowserMob: http://bmp.lightbody.net/
- Get AutomatedTestter.BrowserMob from https://github.com/AutomatedTester/AutomatedTester.BrowserMob
- Get Selenium
- Run following code:

```
 // Supply the path to the Browsermob Proxy batch file
        Server server =
            new Server(
                @"path\to\browsermob-proxy.bat");
        server.Start();

        Client client = server.CreateProxy();
        client.RemapHost("host", "ip address");
        client.NewHar("google");

        var seleniumProxy = new Proxy { HttpProxy = client.SeleniumProxy };
        var profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.SetProxyPreferences(seleniumProxy);
        // Navigate to the page to retrieve performance stats for
        var driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com.vn");


        // Get the performance stats
        HarResult harData = client.GetHar();

        AutomatedTester.BrowserMob.HAR.Log log = harData.Log;
        AutomatedTester.BrowserMob.HAR.Entry[] entries = log.Entries;
        foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
            AutomatedTester.BrowserMob.HAR.Request request = entry.Request;
            var url = request.Url;
            var time = entry.Time;
            Console.WriteLine("Url: " + url + " - Time: " + time);
        }



        driver.Quit();
        client.Close();
        server.Stop();
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate you can use the web performance tests that are built into the product. There is also a Test Edition of Visual Studio 2008 that does web performance tests.  Test results can be stored in a SQL Server database and you can control the metrics you wish to trend.

Comment: FYI, it's the same web performance tests in 2008 as in 2010, but with more features in 2010.

Answer (score 0):

When I plan a Web Performance Test of Ajax, I prefer to generate request and parse response from Server side with C# code.

Commonly, the challenge of performance is testing data design, handling multi-threading simulation client and analysis different issue situations.

Generally, almost all of my Ajax program communicate with ASP.NET MVC / WCF Service with JSON. I can easy build JSon simulation client. The client is multi-threading program, and config different amount thread to call Ajax services. I prefer to use JSon.NET to reading and writing JSON. JSon.NET is a popular JSON framework for .NET, at [Json.CodePlex.com](http://json.codeplex.com/)

In the performance test program , you can use Log2NET to record each operation cost. You can analysis the log file for what you need.

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

There are some inbuilt tools in Visual Studio to test performance of an application, but they are not very good. If you are really serious about your application you will have to use some third party professional tools.